# JAAS custom LoginModule error messages with Struts 1 and Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts-1, jaas

I have an application that is using JAAS LoginModule for authorization. I need to show different error messages. One message when user entered wrong login or password and other message when user's account was blocked after X unsuccessful attemps.
LoginModule supports only one error page. The only way that I see is to pass message to JSP-page.
How can I pass custom message to JSP-page from LoginModule? 
The only way that I see is to store this message in session and retrieve it on JSP-page. But I don't know how to get session in LoginModule. 
I know there is PolicyContext in JBoss and ActionContext in Struts 2. But I am using Struts 1 (legacy code) and Tomcat. 
Is there any solution?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: No I haven't. I am just showing this message to user: "You entered worng password. Your account will be blocked after 5 unsuccessfulll atempts."
So if you'll find something, please share.